# Restore Luster Craft

Tags: cleaning

I recently inherited a very old but complete set of Luster Craft stainless steel waterless cookware. I know I can use barkeepers friend to clean but what should I use to polish the steel and the handles?  I already have a set of chef’s ware and plan to restore/refurbish the Luster craft for my daughter and keep them in the family.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use barkeepers friend on the steel?

Comment: Does bar keepers friend restore shine to the exterior of the pots? I thought it would be too abradive to restore the shine, but hey, if it will do that too, then that’s great!

Comment: It's worked for me; the abrasives in BKF are specifically softer than steel or glass so that it won't mess stuff up.  I wouldn't use it on copper, though.

Comment: Also, the really old rolled steel cookware tends to be made of harder steel than inexpensive cookware is today.  We have some old Duncan Hines ware, and you'd have to use sandpaper to scratch it.

Comment: There is a specific cookware formulation of BKF available now too - "Cookware Cleanser and Polisher".

Answer (score 1):

Given you're going with BKF for the cleaning, I'd recommend the specific cookware formulation - https://www.barkeepersfriend.com/cleaning-products/cookware-cleanser-polish/

Answer (score 0):

I have used Cameo Stainless Steel cleaner for years...my set of Lustre Craft is 63 years old and still in great shape.  Cameo cleaner is also a powder and it is getting more difficult to find in grocery stores.  I'm told it still is available at WalMart.